# AndroidX PreferenceFragmentCompat No view found for id id/content for fragment

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx

I referred to [this document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#kotlin).

#### SettingsActivity.kt:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    class DispatcherFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            this.setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_items, rootKey)
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        this.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, DispatcherFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

#### settings_items.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            app:key="notifications"
            app:title="Enable message notifications"/>

    <Preference
            app:key="feedback"
            app:title="Send feedback"
            app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

When I ran the program, I got an error:`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07004c (<my_package_name>:id/content) for fragment DispatcherFragment{24598125 (ae4eec60-a4c6-404b-b899-7fb0e6b378f2) id=0x7f07004c}`

It seems that I did the same thing as Google Docs, but did not get the expected results.

Is there anything missing from this? Or are there other matters needing attention that are not mentioned in the document?

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07004c (:id/content) for fragment DispatcherFragment{24598125 (ae4eec60-a4c6-404b-b899-7fb0e6b378f2) id=0x7f07004c}

It means that  `this.supportFragmentManager.replace(R.id.content, DispatcherFragment())` is not able to find the view defined with `R.id.content`.
The id passed into `supportFragmentManager.replace()`, in your case `R.id.content`, must be a child of the layout specified in `setContentView()` of your `Activity`.

Something like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //...
}
```

where the layout is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have already solved this problem.  According to Google's documents, there is no need to `setContentView`.  Just change `R.id.content` to `android.R.id.content`.

Comment: @forDream Yes it is correct if you are using the default view. If you would like to use a custom layout you have to use the setContentView().